# Dynamic GroupBoxes always align to top

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, groupbox

I have this application where several groupboxes are in a vertical line. They can be enabled and disabled individually. I want to always align the groupboxes to the top, no matter if the ones normally being in between to is enabled or not.

Say we have three groupboxes (1, 2, 3). The middle one (2) gets disabled. Normally the two other boxes (1,3) locations wont be affected by this. But I want the last groupbox (3) to then take the place that the middle groupbox (2) would normally be in.

Any ideas how to accomplish this the most simple way?

This is what im doing at the moment which isnt good enough for scaling

```
        if (isForgeIncluded == "True" | isForgeIncluded == "true")
        {
            forgeBox.Visible = true;
            if (headerPic == "False" | headerPic == "false")
            {
                PictureBox1.Visible = false;
                forgeBox.Location = new Point(6, 5);
                pathBox.Location = new Point(6, 112);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            forgeBox.Visible = false;
            if (headerPic == "False" | headerPic == "false")
            {
                PictureBox1.Visible = false;
                pathBox.Location = new Point(6, 5);
            }
            else
            {
                pathBox.Location = new Point(6, 168);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you show how the GroupBox are being created? Are you trying to disable them or make them invisible? If they are setting on a Layout Control you may need to make the LayoutControl invisible.

Answer (score 1):

set groupbox2 location(x,y) to  groupbox3 location(x,y) while your groupbox2 disables - might be from a specific event.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a solution to this, which is "more dynamic" but not 100% dynamic, as i will have to go add new GroupBoxes to an array manually. However, this does work, and takes care of the picturebox in the beginning

```
int nextBoxLocation = 0;
int boxHeightAdd = 0;
int spacing = 6;

if (headerPic == "True" | headerPic == "true")
{
    PictureBox1.Visible = true;
    nextBoxLocation = PictureBox1.Height + spacing;
}
if (isForgeIncluded == "True" | isForgeIncluded == "true") 
{ 
    forgeBox.Visible = true; 
}

GroupBox[] boxes = {forgeBox , pathBox , typeBox};

foreach(GroupBox box in boxes) 
{
    if (box.Visible == true)
    {
         box.Location = new Point(6, nextBoxLocation);
         boxHeightAdd = box.Height;
    }
    if (box.Name == "pathBox" && (minecraftPathVar == Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft")))
    {
         defRadioPath.Visible = false;
         minecraftRadioPath.Visible = false;
         box.Height = 75;
         boxHeightAdd = 75;
    }
    nextBoxLocation += boxHeightAdd + spacing;
    boxHeightAdd = 0;
}
```